# FFMPEG: How to shorten silence at the beginning of an audio file

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I would like to shorten the silence at the beginning of my audio.
Currently I use this command:

```
ffmpeg -i input.flac -af silenceremove=1:0:-50dB output.flac
```

It works, but the problem is: It removes the silence completely. But I want to have a little silence of the beginning of the audio file.
(Because some players don't play the first milliseconds of the file, so there would be something missing.)

So I have input files with for example 2 seconds of silence at the beginning and I want to shorten this silence from 2 to 0.5 seconds, NOT REMOVE it completely.

Is this possible with ffmpeg? How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two more options to set.

```
ffmpeg -i input.flac -af silenceremove=1:0:-50dB:stop_duration=0.5:leave_silence=1 output.flac
```

---

Since this proves ineffective, the cruder method is to add back half a second of silence,

```
ffmpeg -i input.flac -af "silenceremove=1:0:-50dB,adelay=500|500" output.flac
```

This will add 500 ms of silence at the beginning to a stereo stream.

Comment: Tryed it and this also removes the silence completely for me. Doesn't work as I want it to work.